# wxWidgets -> Show web page links

Tags: c++, hyperlink, wxwidgets, html

How do I show a "clickable" webpage link in a wxFrame/Window/Dialog/Whatever?

wxWidgets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [wxHyperlinkCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/classwx_hyperlink_ctrl.html).